# Generated JSON in wrong format

Tags: java, json, jpa

I have namedQuery defined in this manner

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Emp.findAll", 
query = " select new test.entity.Emp(o.empNo, o.salary, p.projectId, p.projectName)
from Emp o inner join o.project p ")
```

In service class, I have

```
@GET
@Path("/projects")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Emp> findAll() {
    return this.queryFindAll();
```

And generated JSON is this format

```
[{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projects":{"projectId":209,"projectName":"Z560"}}]
```

Ideally I would like to generate JSON in the following format

```
[{"empNo":"2390","empName":"JAMES","projectId":"209","projectName":"Z560"}]
```

How can I do this?

Update 1

```
@GET
    @Path("/projects")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object findAll() throws IOException{
        String empAsJson = null;
        List<Emp> list = queryFindAll();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        empAsJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);        
        return empAsJson;
    }
```

Comment: Is your Emp entity with a list of Project?

Comment: @uaiHebert Yes, it is like     `@JsonBackReference("kas")@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<Emp> empList;` and in Emp     `@JsonManagedReference("kas")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID", 
                referencedColumnName = "PROJECT_ID")
    private Project project ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like projects is getting serialized out as a map/object, you just need to make it an array of maps or objects.

Updated with pseudocode:

```
List<Map<String,String>> rolledupEmps = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
for(Emp emp : emps){
     Map<String,String> em = mapper.readValue(emp, HashMap.class);
     em.put("projectId",em.get("projects")?!=null:em.get("projects").get("projectId"),"");
     em.put("projectName",em.get("projects")?!=null:em.get("projects").get("projectName"),"");
     em.remove(""projects"");
     rolledupEmps.put(em);
}
return mapper.writeValueAsString(rolledupEmps);
```

Comment: Create a List<Map> from List<Emp> that has all properties rolled up into a flattened object.

Comment: I have updated my question as update 1, I am using `ObjectMapper`, however still I am getting the same output.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I am having an issue with this line `mapper.readValue(emp, HashMap.class);` as it complains about wring argument types.

Comment: Yes, that did solve that error. I have an error at this line though `Map<String,String> em = objectMapper.readValue(emp.toString(),HashMap.class);` And error is `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')`

Comment: I have created another question for the above error http://stackoverflow.com/q/27520496/599528

Comment: What does emp.toString() print, Did you try using convertValue(), if not please try that.

Comment: emp.toString prints as `test.emp.entity.Emp@78c5cc63`

Comment: objectMapper.convertValue(emp, HashMap.class); does solve that issue. But em.get("projects.projectId") is always `null`. Neither this code works `em.get("projects").get("projectId")`

Comment: Based on your initial JSON em.get("projects").get("projectId") is what you should be accessing. Please try to debug /inspect your code, I'm assuming that you have an IDE like Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ ?

Comment: `em.get("projects").get("projectId")` provide compilation error saying `get("projectId")` doesn't exist.

Comment: projects will be a map, add a cast to map, and call get("projectId")